# Starcraft 2: is it possible to switch languages?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have bought what appears to be Polish version of Starcraft 2, will I be able to play it in English? Interfaces, sounds, etc.?

Just wanna be sure before I open the case and install it, so that I could ask for refund in the worst case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Your game license should allow you to download any language available in your region. As your region would be EU, you would have access to the great britain version of the client. If for some reason you have any issues, you can also follow the instructions located [here](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=139082) to work around it.

Of note though, the actual DVD's will probably contain only the polish version, so you will need to download the english language pack. I presume you'll have no problem accessing an internet connection though.

Comment: Apparently this is the only "official" way :(

Answer (score 1):

From my DVD copy of the English version, it only contains the `enUS` "asset" and "data" files on the media.  The collective localized files are relatively large, and I doubt multiple languages would be able to fit onto one DVD, assuming the videos are re-rendered for a different language versus just dubbing or subtitling (I wouldn't know).

As you suggested, you may be able to get around it by downloading the installer in whichever language from Blizzard, but some platforms (Valve's Steam) won't let you use CD-keys outside of the proper region.  If you're in Europe though, it should be fine.